# Importing documentCreateElement function from Webkit

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

I am trying to import `documentGetElementById` function for use in `Reflex FRP`. I tried the import below but can't find the function (which according to hackage should be there):

```
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> import Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.DOM.Document
*Main Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.DOM.Document> :t documentGetElementById
<interactive>:1:1: error:
   Variable not in scope: documentGetElementById
```

I will appreciate help with resolving this. I am running latest Reflex platform build with `ghc 8.0.1` on mac where webkit works now. I see the same problem on Linux as well. So, it doesn't seem to be platform-specific.

I also did [github code search](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-dom/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=documentGetElementById) on `ghcjs-dom` but `documentGetElementById` doesn't show up. So, perhaps it has been moved somewhere else?

Comment: Are you using Reflex FRP *in normal Haskell*, or were you thinking of compiling your program to JavaScript?

Comment: All the recent uses on github do `import GHCJS.DOM.Document `

Comment: @TikhonJelvis, I plan to compile it to JS, but it will be nice to have ghci access during dev for debugging in repl, if possible.

Comment: @Michael, yep, I tried that as well. It doesn't work either because that module doesn't export it any more.

Comment: @Michael, it is now renamed to `getElementById`. So, that will work. You can post it as an answer if you will like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`documentGetElementById` has been renamed to `getElementById` after `ghcjs-dom` refactoring. So, an import like below would work:

```
*Main> import Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.DOM.Document
*Main Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.DOM.Document> :t getElementById 
getElementById
  :: (DocumentClass self, System.Glib.UTFString.GlibString string,
      MonadIO m) =>
     self -> string -> m (Maybe Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.Types.Element)
```